# opencv read transperant logo

Tags: python, opencv, transparency

I am trying to create a python script that recognizes logo in a picture. Here is my code:

```
import cv2

main_pic = "./sto-procenta-budni.png"
product_logo = "./sto-procenta-budni-logo.png"
product_logo_transperant = "./sto-procenta-budni-logo-transperant.png"

main_pic_read = cv2.imread(main_pic, cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
product_logo_read = cv2.imread(product_logo, cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
product_logo_transperant_read = cv2.imread(product_logo_transperant, cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)

search_product = cv2.matchTemplate(main_pic_read, product_logo_read, cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)
prod_min_val, prod_max_val, prod_min_loc, prod_max_loc = cv2.minMaxLoc(search_product)
print(prod_min_val, prod_max_val, prod_min_loc, prod_max_loc)

search_product_transperant = cv2.matchTemplate(main_pic_read, product_logo_transperant_read, cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)
prod_min_val_transperant, prod_max_val_transperant, prod_min_loc_transperant, prod_max_loc_transperant = cv2.minMaxLoc(search_product_transperant)
print(prod_min_val_transperant, prod_max_val_transperant, prod_min_loc_transperant, prod_max_loc_transperant)
```

Code works good.

If I try to use transparent logo `product_logo_transperant = "./sto-procenta-budni-logo-transperant.png"` I have got this error:

```
    search_product_transperant = cv2.matchTemplate(main_pic_read, product_logo_transperant_read, cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.5.5) /io/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/templmatch.cpp:1164: error: (-215:Assertion failed) (depth == CV_8U || depth == CV_32F) && type == _templ.type() && _img.dims() <= 2 in function 'matchTemplate'
```

Can I use transparent picture as template?
Where my code is wrong?

here are test pictures

[image: sto-procenta-budni-logo-transperant.png]

[image: sto-procenta-budni-logo.png]

[image: sto-procenta-budni.png]

Comment: When using a transparent picture there are 4 channels in it. The error says number of dimensions do not match. While reading avoid the last alpha channel

Comment: Thank you @JeruLuke,
Does it mean that I can't use transparent logo in my case?

Comment: You can. You just need to use the first three channels of the logo `product_logo_transperant_read`

Answer (score 0):

here is my working code

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

main_pic = "./sto-procenta-budni-min.png"
product_logo = "./sto-procenta-budni-logo.png"
product_logo_transperant = "./sto-procenta-budni-logo-transperant.png"

main_pic_read = cv2.imread(main_pic, cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
product_logo_read = cv2.imread(product_logo, cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
product_logo_transperant_read = cv2.imread(product_logo_transperant, cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)


search_product = cv2.matchTemplate(main_pic_read, product_logo_read, cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)
prod_min_val, prod_max_val, prod_min_loc, prod_max_loc = cv2.minMaxLoc(search_product)
print(prod_min_val, prod_max_val, prod_min_loc, prod_max_loc)

logo = product_logo_transperant_read[:,:,0:3]
alpha = product_logo_transperant_read[:,:,3]
alpha = cv2.merge([alpha,alpha,alpha])

search_product_transperant = cv2.matchTemplate(main_pic_read, logo, cv2.TM_CCORR_NORMED, mask=alpha)
prod_min_val_transperant, prod_max_val_transperant, prod_min_loc_transperant, prod_max_loc_transperant = cv2.minMaxLoc(search_product_transperant)
print(prod_min_val_transperant, prod_max_val_transperant, prod_min_loc_transperant, prod_max_loc_transperant)
```